# Spark "first" Window function is taking much longer than "last"

Tags: performance, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I'm working on a pyspark routine to interpolate the missing values in a configuration table.

Imagine a table of configuration values that go from 0 to 50,000. The user specifies a few data points in between (say at 0, 50, 100, 500, 2000, 500000) and we interpolate the remainder. My solution mostly follows [this blog post](https://walkenho.github.io/interpolating-time-series-p2-spark/) quite closely, except I'm not using any UDFs.

In troubleshooting the performance of this (takes ~3 minutes) I found that one particular window function is taking all of the time, and everything else I'm doing takes mere seconds.

Here is the main area of interest - where I use window functions to fill in the previous and next user-supplied configuration values:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window, functions as F

# Create partition windows that are required to generate new rows from the ones provided
win_last = Window.partitionBy('PORT_TYPE', 'loss_process').orderBy('rank').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
win_next = Window.partitionBy('PORT_TYPE', 'loss_process').orderBy('rank').rowsBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing)

# Join back in the provided config table to populate the "known" scale factors
df_part1 = (df_scale_factors_template
  .join(df_users_config, ['PORT_TYPE', 'loss_process', 'rank'], 'leftouter')
  # Add computed columns that can lookup the prior config and next config for each missing value
  .withColumn('last_rank', F.last( F.col('rank'),         ignorenulls=True).over(win_last))
  .withColumn('last_sf',   F.last( F.col('scale_factor'), ignorenulls=True).over(win_last))
).cache()
debug_log_dataframe(df_part1 , 'df_part1') # Force a .count() and time Part1

df_part2 = (df_part1
  .withColumn('next_rank', F.first(F.col('rank'),         ignorenulls=True).over(win_next))
  .withColumn('next_sf',   F.first(F.col('scale_factor'), ignorenulls=True).over(win_next))
).cache()
debug_log_dataframe(df_part2 , 'df_part2') # Force a .count() and time Part2

df_part3 = (df_part2
  # Implements standard linear interpolation: y = y1 + ((y2-y1)/(x2-x1)) * (x-x1)
  .withColumn('scale_factor', 
              F.when(F.col('last_rank')==F.col('next_rank'), F.col('last_sf')) # Handle div/0 case
              .otherwise(F.col('last_sf') + ((F.col('next_sf')-F.col('last_sf'))/(F.col('next_rank')-F.col('last_rank'))) * (F.col('rank')-F.col('last_rank'))))
  .select('PORT_TYPE', 'loss_process', 'rank', 'scale_factor')
).cache()
debug_log_dataframe(df_part3, 'df_part3', explain: True) # Force a .count() and time Part3
```

The above used to be a single chained dataframe statement, but I've since split it into 3 parts so that I could isolate the part that's taking so long. The results are:

- `Part 1: Generated  8 columns and 300006 rows in   0.65 seconds`
- `Part 2: Generated 10 columns and 300006 rows in 189.55 seconds`
- `Part 3: Generated  4 columns and 300006 rows in   0.24 seconds`

---

### Why do my calls to `first()` over `Window.unboundedFollowing` take so much longer than `last()` over `Window.unboundedPreceding`?

---

**Some notes to head off questions / concerns:**

- `debug_log_dataframe` is just a helper function to force the dataframe execution/cache with a `.Count()` and time it to yield the above logs.
- We're actually operating on 6 config tables of 50001 rows at once (hence the partitioning and row count)
- As a sanity check, I've ruled out the effects of `cache()` reuse by explicitly `unpersist()`ing before timing subsequent runs - I'm quite confident in the above measurements.

**Physical Plan**:
To help answer this question, I call `explain()` on the result of part3 to confirm, among other things, that caching is having the desired effect. Here it is annotated to highlight the problem area:
[image: explain]

The only differences I can see is that:

- The first two calls (to `last`) show `RunningWindowFunction`, whereas the calls to `next` just read `Window`
- Part 1 had a *(3) next to it, but Part 2 does not.

**Some things I tried**:

- I tried further splitting part 2 into separate dataframes - the result is that each `first` statement takes half of the total time (~98 seconds)
- I tried reversing the order in which I generate these columns (e.g. placing the calls to 'last' after the calls to 'first') but there's no difference. Whichever dataframe ends up containing the calls to `first` is the slow one.

I feel like I've done as much digging as I can and am kind of hoping a spark expert will take one look at know where this time is coming from.

Comment: I've heard more than one DBA make a blanket statement along the lines of "Avoid OLAP functions, they are more trouble than they're worth" and while I don't always follow that advice, seeing stuff like this definitely helps me understand where they're coming from.

Comment: Spark 3.1.1 by the way, for anyone wondering if this is a version issue.

Comment: I created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-36844 on the off-chance that this is unintended behaviour.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The solution that doesn't answer the question**

In trying various things to speed up my routine, it occurred to me to try re-rewriting my usages of `first()` to just be usages of `last()` with a reversed sort order.

So rewriting this:

```py
win_next = (Window.partitionBy('PORT_TYPE', 'loss_process')
  .orderBy('rank').rowsBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing))

df_part2 = (df_part1
  .withColumn('next_rank', F.first(F.col('rank'),         ignorenulls=True).over(win_next))
  .withColumn('next_sf',   F.first(F.col('scale_factor'), ignorenulls=True).over(win_next))
)
```

As this:

```py
win_next = (Window.partitionBy('PORT_TYPE', 'loss_process')
  .orderBy(F.desc('rank')).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))

df_part2 = (df_part1
  .withColumn('next_rank', F.last(F.col('rank'),         ignorenulls=True).over(win_next))
  .withColumn('next_sf',   F.last(F.col('scale_factor'), ignorenulls=True).over(win_next))
)
```

Much to my amazement, this actually solved the performance problem, and now the entire dataframe is generated in just 3 seconds. I'm pleased, but still vexed.

As I somewhat predicted, the query plan now includes a new SORT step before creating these next two columns, and they've changed from `Window` to  `RunningWindowFunction` as the first two. Here's the new plan (without the code broken up into 3 separate cached parts anymore, because that was just to troubleshoot performance):
[image]

As for the question:

> Why do my calls to first() over Window.unboundedFollowing take so much longer than last() over Window.unboundedPreceding?

I'm hoping someone can still answer this, for academic reasons

Comment: If you're still curious about this, I was looking around and found this issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-36770. There's a link to a PR in it but it hasn't been merged.
TL;DR It seems like UnboundedFollowingWindowFunctionFrame is O(N^2), while UnboundedPrecedingWindowFunctionFrame is O(N)